# Can't import gym; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym'

Tags: pip, anaconda, openai-gym

[image]

Can't import gym;

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym'
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems to me that you're trying to use https://pypi.org/p/gym.

You'd want to run in the terminal (before typing `python`, when the `$` prompt is visible):

```
pip install gym
```

After that, if you run `python`, you should be able to run `import gym`.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you're installing gym, so

```
pip install gym
```

is unnecessary.

Please, try:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path')
```

where **path** is directory with **gym module**.

Comment: how can i find the path?

Comment: I think this works but is there anyway so that I could avoid setting the path every time?

Comment: I make research and I think it is issue with anaconda, some people have the same problem like you: https://github.com/stevenpjg/ddpg-aigym/issues/9, the last question 8 hours ago.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll go with it for now then!

Comment: Can you select my answser as the best? Thanks!

Comment: One can find the path of the gym package in conda prompt with: `pip show gym` under the description: `Location: `.

Answer (score 2):

run this:

```
pip install gym
```

Then run your "import gym" again.

Comment: Yutongs-MBP:~ yutongyan$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gym
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym'
>>>

Comment: That's what I got :(

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Anaconda as your package manager, use this to install gym

`conda install -c conda-forge gym`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me to hope its work for you also!!

```
pip install --user gym
```